# How to animate a Path without creating a SubView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, core-animation

Is it possible to animate a Path without creating a SubView?

Eg.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var end = 0.0
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    end += 100
                }
            }
           
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: .zero)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: end, y: end))
            }
            .stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

I know we can extract the `Path` into a SubView and use the `animatableData` property to animate it, however, I was wondering if this is achievable without doing that (animating the `Path` directly).

**What I've tried:**
I thought making `ContentView` animatable and using the required `animatableData` property within `ContentView` itself would help.

Eg.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var end = 0.0

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { end }
        set { end = newValue }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    end += 100
                }
            }
           
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: .zero)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: end, y: end))
            }
            .stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work unfortunately. I also tried adding `.animation` modifiers to `Path` but that still didn't do the job.

Is it possible to animate this `Path` without wrapping it in a `Shape` or a different type of SubView? I wan't to be able to change `end` and have the change be animated without wrapping the `Path` in a different view.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.trim** modifier with **.animation** modifier.

```
struct PathAnimationView: View {
    @State private var end = 0.0
    @State private var trimStart: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var trimEnd: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Press me") {
                withAnimation {
                    trimStart = 0.0
                    end += 100
                    trimEnd = 1
                }
            }
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: .zero)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: end, y: end))
            }
            .trim(from: trimStart, to: trimEnd)
            .stroke()
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1.0), value: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Limitation:
.trim will animate path from start to end once.

So better user **Shape** class to do this.

Comment: It doesn't work if I keep pressing "press me". I want the `Path` to animate every / any time I change `end`. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Yes, for that you need use Shape.